# Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression

Tags: matlab

I am trying to evaluate the following expression:

```
 (-a(3)*(4*b(1,1)*b(2,2)-b(1,2)*b(2,1))+b(3,2)*(2*b(1,1)*a(2)+b(1,2)*b(2,1)))/(2*b(3,3)*(4*b(1,1)*b(2,2)-b(1,2)*b(2,l,1))-b(3,2)(2*b(1,1)*b(2,3)-b(1,2)*b(2,1)))
```

It is for expression (in latex):

```
$\left(\frac{-a_3 (4\beta_{11}\beta_{22}-\beta_{12}\beta_{21} ) +\beta_{32}(2\beta_{11}a_2+\beta_{12}\beta_{21})}
      {2\beta_{33} (4\beta_{11}\beta_{22}-\beta_{12}\beta_{21} ) -\beta_{32}(2\beta_{11}\beta_{23} - \beta_{12}\beta_{21})}\right)$
```

Matlab keeps complaining that:

```
Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.
```

I want to check if I have the simplification right and would need such expression to be evaluated.

Comment: Use some temporary variables, don't try to do all of that in one line.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add an asterisk after `b(3,2)`. Currently the term that starts with `b(3,2)` is like this:

```
b(3,2)(2*b(1,1)*b(2,3)-b(1,2)*b(2,1))
```

You should change it to

```
b(3,2)*(2*b(1,1)*b(2,3)-b(1,2)*b(2,1))
```

The problem is that Matlab interprets that as indexing `b(3,2)` which is already an indexed expression.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your matrix `b` is two-dimensional, but your expression contains `b(2,l,1)` which has three subscripts.

The original formula didn't have any `l` in it.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ben, this is a valid point, but even correcting the typo, the same error message keeps pumping up:  I used "(-a(3)*(4*b(1,1)*b(2,2)-b(1,2)*b(2,1))+b(3,2)*(2*b(1,1)*a(2)+b(1,2)*b(2,1)))/(2*b(3,3)*(4*b(1,1)*b(2,2)-b(1,2)*b(2,1))-b(3,2)(2*b(1,1)*b(2,3)-b(1,2)*b(2,1)))"

Comment: @llinfeng: Break that into smaller parts